# Dismiss keypad in Android device when input triggers in Ionic

Tags: javascript, android, angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm using syncfusion ej2 Calendar plugin for datepicker but here I'm using only range level ex: today or 1 month or last 7 days options from that plugin. so plugin itself it is providing dropdown options when I trigger calendar.

```
<div class="Datepicker" >
            <ejs-daterangepicker id='daterangepicker'  [(ngModel)]='value' placeholder='Select a range' [startDate]='start' [endDate]='end' [min]='minDate_s' [max]='maxDate_s' [minDays]='minDays' [maxDays]='maxDays'(change)="eJSGetDates($event)">
                <e-presets>
                    <e-preset label="Today" [start]='today' [end]='today'></e-preset>
                    <e-preset label="Yesterday" [start]='yesterday' [end]='yesterday'></e-preset>
                    <e-preset label="This Week" [start]='weekStart' [end]='weekEnd'></e-preset>
                    <e-preset label="This Month" [start]='monthStart' [end]='monthEnd'></e-preset>
                    <e-preset label="Last Month" [start]='lastStart' [end]='lastEnd'></e-preset>
                </e-presets>
            </ejs-daterangepicker>
        </div>
    </div>
```

but the thing is when I call that datepicker keypad showing but I don't want to fire keypad, I want to hide keypad when I trigger calendar.[image]

Comment: which ionic version you are using?

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan I'm working with Ionic3 .

Comment: is there any focus event available for the `daterangepicker`

Comment: Yes there is an event called with  (change)="eJSGetDates($event)" in component.

Comment: change event is emitted if you choose any value right?

Comment: Right, but before emitted the value I want to hide keypad. Sorry did you get my point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189174/discussion-between-sivaramakrishnan-and-mepraveenk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After refereed documentation of plugin API 
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/api/daterangepicker/dateRangePickerModel/#allowedit

I found a solution for my above question
There are some properties provided by plugin API "allowEdit"
if we have given allowedit=false. my requirement fulfilled. we are not able to change the input value but we can choose the date from the modal popup.
we don't need to install the native plugin for the keyboard.

```
<div class="Datepicker" >
            <ejs-daterangepicker [allowEdit] = 'false' id='daterangepicker'  [(ngModel)]='value' placeholder='Select a range' [startDate]='start' [endDate]='end' [min]='minDate_s' [max]='maxDate_s' [minDays]='minDays' [maxDays]='maxDays'(change)="eJSGetDates($event)">
                <e-presets>
                    <e-preset label="Today" [start]='today' [end]='today'></e-preset>
                    <e-preset label="Yesterday" [start]='yesterday' [end]='yesterday'></e-preset>
                    <e-preset label="This Week" [start]='weekStart' [end]='weekEnd'></e-preset>
                    <e-preset label="This Month" [start]='monthStart' [end]='monthEnd'></e-preset>
                    <e-preset label="Last Month" [start]='lastStart' [end]='lastEnd'></e-preset>
                </e-presets>
            </ejs-daterangepicker>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import the native plugin `keyboard` to show or hide the `keyboard` manually so you can try this

Install the plugin using this command `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard`

Import the plugin and add them in the `constructor()` in your ts file

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

constructor(private keyboard: Keyboard) { }
```

Add a function and when you click the control the focus event triggers and this function gets called 
and hides the keyboard

```
focusEvent(){
this.keyboard.hide();
}
```

In html

```
<div class="Datepicker" >
            <ejs-daterangepicker id='daterangepicker' (focus)="focusEvent()" [(ngModel)]='value' placeholder='Select a range' [startDate]='start' [endDate]='end' [min]='minDate_s' [max]='maxDate_s' [minDays]='minDays' [maxDays]='maxDays'(change)="eJSGetDates($event)">
                <e-presets>
                    <e-preset label="Today" [start]='today' [end]='today'></e-preset>
                    <e-preset label="Yesterday" [start]='yesterday' [end]='yesterday'></e-preset>
                    <e-preset label="This Week" [start]='weekStart' [end]='weekEnd'></e-preset>
                    <e-preset label="This Month" [start]='monthStart' [end]='monthEnd'></e-preset>
                    <e-preset label="Last Month" [start]='lastStart' [end]='lastEnd'></e-preset>
                </e-presets>
            </ejs-daterangepicker>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Refer the documentation of keyboard plugin here [keyboard plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/keyboard/)